# Wiring of sub panel in a detached garage

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have 240V service (40 amp) to my detached garage using 8-2 UF wire.  This was installed in the 90's.  It feeds 4 120V circuits. I recently was looking at the sub panel where the black and white are hot and the bare ground is serving as both ground and neutral back to the main panel.  I never has a problem but is it OK to use the bare ground in this way?  If not what should I do?  Also, there is no ground rod at the sub panel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [2 wire sub-panel corrective action](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/93565/2-wire-sub-panel-corrective-action)

Comment: Note-- there are some other issues discussed in that question ^ but they have the same setup as you describe here: 2-wire hot and a ground back to a main panel with no wire acting as a dedicated neutral, and that's the biggest issue tackled by the existing top answer there as well.

Comment: The simple answer is this was code legal when installed and is grandfathered today because the code change that changed the rules were in 99.  Internet only electricians take pages and don’t make this simple statement. Today code requires a 4 wire feed and if a detached structure an additional grounding electrode system. 

If you want to make safer add GFCI protection.  this is required for all receptacles in a garage today

Comment: How open are you to digging up and replacing the cable in question?

Comment: The inspector may give credit for grandfathering... the reaper doesn't.

Comment: Digging up is the easy part but snaking through to the main panel while laying on my back in the crawl space isn't. But I could do it.  Since it is grandfathered I don't have to do this.  Can someone give me specific examples of what could go wrong with existing setup. I need some incentive to go ahead and make the change.  If I do, I would use 8-3 UF-B wire and burry 24" without conduit.  When coming above ground, use conduit starting 18" deep.  Add an insulated neutral bar in the existing sub panel.  Add 8' copper ground rod and connect to ground bar in sub panel. Thanks for your help.